# camera not open in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I m beginner in xamarin.I have existing project for android and ios in xamarin.I have open camera successfully in ios but not open in android.following is my code.

```
static async Task<Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile> TakePicture()
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                //var imageProcessing = DependencyService.Get<IImageProcessing> ();
                //              imageProcessing.TakePhoto ();
                //              return null;

                var options = new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions();

                //options.Directory = imageProcessing.GetImageDir ();
                return await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(options);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I have added permission on **manifest.xml**.when I run project in my device it ask for permission but not opening camera.

please help me to shortout this issue.

Comment: did you add additional code to Android project?

Comment: Which OS version are you using?

Comment: no.....@miechooy

Comment: this code common for ios and android

Comment: @DennisSchröer all os

Answer (score 0):

To use Media Plugin for Xamarin, you need to do some additional required setup as described in `readme.txt`.

### Additional Required Setup (Please Read!)

### Android

In  your BaseActivity or MainActivity (for Xamarin.Forms) add this code:

Add usings:

```
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;
```

Then add to Activity:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, Permission[] grantResults)
{
    PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions are required, but the library will automatically add this for you. Additionally, if your users are running Marshmallow the Plugin will automatically prompt them for runtime permissions.

**ANDROID N**
If your application targets Android N (API 24) or newer, you must use version 2.6.0+.

You must also add a few additional configuration files to adhere to the new strict mode:

1.) Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml inside the  tags:

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" 
                android:authorities="YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME.fileprovider" 
                android:exported="false" 
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" 
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

`YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME` must be set to your app package name!

2.) Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called `file_paths.xml`

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME must be set to your app package name!

You can read more at: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

### Android Current Activity Setup

This plugin uses the [Current Activity Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md) to get access to the current Android Activity. Be sure to complete the full setup if a MainApplication.cs file was not automatically added to your application. Please fully read through the [Current Activity Plugin Documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md). At an absolute minimum you must set the following in your Activity's OnCreate method:

`csharp
Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this;`

It is highly recommended that you use a custom Application that are outlined in the [Current Activity Plugin Documentation](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: when I add Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity = this; oncreate method.error like   can not implicit convert type 'villagevesal.mainapplication to 'android.app.activity'

Comment: @Maulikshah It should be added in MainActivity's OnCreate method, not MainApplication.

Answer (score 0):

use this intent

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
                BitmapHelper._file = new File(BitmapHelper.*dir, String.Format("myProfileTemp*{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));

```
            Android.Net.Uri uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(this.BaseContext, "com.AppName.app.fileprovider", BitmapHelper._file);
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, uri);
            StartActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score -1):

add AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.AppName.app.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
```

Comment: Add a new folder called xml into your Resources folder and add a new XML file called file_paths.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path path="Android/data/com.company.product" name="files_root" />
<external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>